# flex post to secured serveur

Tags: apache-flex, internet-explorer, spring-mvc, https

I'm posting data from Flex application to Tomcat secured Web Server.
 the Url parameters reached Spring controller in Chrome and FireFox.However ,in IE I get null ! is there any wrong in posting data in IE in Https ?

Comment: if I install the certeficate Manually It works . but it is a workaround i want to avoid.

Comment: Are you using a self-signed certificate?  If so; I think you have install the cert manually.  If you have a "Formal" cert; then it should work w/o problems.

Comment: I have a selfsigned certteficate . is there any other solution . it seems weired from client point of view to intstall the certeficate manually !

Comment: I could say that it seems weird from a security point of view to use a self signed certificate.  For development, just manually accept your self-signed cert.  For production, purchase a cert or don't use HTTPS.